# How to Auto Increment a field with the 1st number available in a multi primary key table

Tags: sql, primary-key, auto-increment

I need to increment a secondary field in a database, but when the left most primary key changes I need that field to start again in 1.

I used autoIncrement but when the left key changes the number keeps on going up

Example:

```
    Table
    key1, key 2 
    1     1
    1     2
    1     3
    1     4
    2     1
    2     2
    1     5
    2     3
    2     4
```

I just want to know if theres a way of doing this directly in SQL when creating a field or if I need to run a previous query everytime just to know what the max(key 2) is....

thanks for the help

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: Yes Columns, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You should define your table as:

```
create table examples (
    example_id int auto_increment primary key,  -- or identity, or generated always as, or serial depending on your database
    key1 int
);
```

Then you can create a view that does what you want:

```
create view v_example as
   select e.*, row_number() over (partition by key1 order by example_id) as key2
   from examples e;
```

That is, do the calculation on the fly.  Maintaining the second key value when there are inserts, updates, and deletes to the table is quite cumbersome.

Comment: I was hoping that SQL had something like this implemented,